# z-index is still working on my hamburger icon

Tags: css, z-index

I have made the mistake before when using z-index of forgetting to add a `display` attribute. My `#brgr` hamburger icon does not show above all other elements.

I have set its `z-index` to 100, higher than any other element.

What doesn't it like about my header?

```js
// Navigation
function initNav() {
 // Main
 const $menuTrigger = $('button#brgr');
 const $menuArea = $('#menu');
 // Content
  var $menuExpanded = false;
   $menuTrigger.on('click', function(){
   if (!$menuExpanded) {
    $menuArea.addClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = true;
   } else {
    $menuArea.removeClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = false 
   }
  });
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {

initNav();

});
```

```css
button {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu {
  position:fixed;
  width:calc( 100vw - 59.3%);
  right:calc( -100vw - -59.3%);
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: 200ms all ease;
  z-index:10;
}

#menu.is-out {
  right: 0
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
} 

header a.logo {
  max-width: 175px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

header #brgr {
  width: 35px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

header #brgr span {
  display: block;
  background: #2d2d2d;
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  width: auto;
}

header #brgr:hover span {
  background: grey
}

header .wrapper {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   
    <div class="wrapper">
   
        <a class="logo" href="">
            A S P X
        </a>
    
        <button id="brgr">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </button>

    </div>

</header>

<div id="menu">
    Menu
</div>
```

Comment: z-index is relative to its containing elements. It only has an effect among adjacent elements. Your hamburger menu is inside your `header` element and the `header` element is going under your `#menu` element. You have to add a z-index to your `header` element to bring it on top of the `#menu` element.

Comment: @KodosJohnson I have a background on my fixed header. This will mean that there will be a white strip at the top of my swipe out menu. Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: You can either remove the background, or move the `#brgr` element outside the `header`... at the same level as your `#menu` element and `header` element. You can use absolute positioning it to place the `#brgr` element wherever you want.

Comment: @KodosJohnson great idea. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: np. Probably better to move the `#brgr` element. You don't want your header on top of your menu because then you can't click on anything.

Comment: This article from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) explains the z-index property very well. Its worth the read.

Answer (score 0):

Change `position` to `absolute` to make your `z-index` work:

```js
// Navigation
function initNav() {
 // Main
 const $menuTrigger = $('button#brgr');
 const $menuArea = $('#menu');
 // Content
  var $menuExpanded = false;
   $menuTrigger.on('click', function(){
   if (!$menuExpanded) {
    $menuArea.addClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = true;
   } else {
    $menuArea.removeClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = false 
   }
  });
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {

initNav();

});
```

```css
button {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu {
  position:fixed;
  width:calc( 100vw - 59.3%);
  right:calc( -100vw - -59.3%);
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: 200ms all ease;
  z-index:10;
}

#menu.is-out {
  right: 0
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
} 

  header a.logo {
    max-width: 175px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }

  header #brgr {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
  }

    header #brgr span {
      display: block;
      background: #2d2d2d;
      height: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      width: auto;
    }

    header #brgr:hover span {
      background: grey
    }

header .wrapper {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   
    <div class="wrapper">
   
       <a class="logo" href="">
           A S P X
       </a>
    
         <button id="brgr">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
         </button>

    </div>

  </header>

  <div id="menu">
            Menu
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the `#menu` inside the `header` element, as you may decide sticky your header to the top of the page when scrolling (may be on responsive mode?!), then you can set a higher `z-index` property in order to have it always visible.

```js
// Navigation
function initNav() {
 // Main
 const $menuTrigger = $('button#brgr');
 const $menuArea = $('#menu');
 // Content
  var $menuExpanded = false;
   $menuTrigger.on('click', function(){
   if (!$menuExpanded) {
    $menuArea.addClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = true;
   } else {
    $menuArea.removeClass('is-out');
     $menuExpanded = false 
   }
  });
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {

initNav();

});
```

```css
button {
  background: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu {
  position:fixed;
  width:calc( 100vw - 59.3%);
  right:calc( -100vw - -59.3%);
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  transition: 200ms all ease;
  z-index:10;
}

#menu.is-out {
  right: 0
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
} 

  header a.logo {
    max-width: 175px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }

  header #brgr {
    width: 35px;
    height: auto;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
  }

    header #brgr span {
      display: block;
      background: #2d2d2d;
      height: 2px;
      margin-bottom: 4px;
      width: auto;
    }

    header #brgr:hover span {
      background: grey
    }

header .wrapper {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
   
    <div class="wrapper">
   
       <a class="logo" href="">
           A S P X
       </a>
    
         <button id="brgr">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
         </button>
         
         <div id="menu">
            Menu
          </div>

    </div>

  </header>
```